# Why is this showing both array and object like behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Please consider the below javaScript code.

```js
var obj = /e/.exec("The best things in life are free!");
var k = "";
var x;
for (x in obj) {
  k = k + " " + obj[x] + " " + x + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (obj instanceof Array) + " " + obj[0] + " " + obj[1] + " " + obj.index + "<br>" + k;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Gives an output

```
JavaScript Regular Expressions
true e undefined 2
e 0
2 index
The best things in life are free! input
undefined groups
```

Now in the above code I used `obj[0]`obj[1]`(which are array only notations), and also`obj.index` (which shouldn't have worked for an array ).

Now I really am confused to what `obj` exactly is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now in the above code I used obj[0] , obj[1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type) (which are array only notations)

No, they aren't. For instance:

```js
const obj = {answer: 42, 42: "is the answer"};
const str = "answer";
console.log(obj[str]); // 42
console.log(obj[42]);  // is the answer
```

> .... and also obj.index (which shouldn't have worked for an array )

Yes, they should. :-)

Standard arrays in javaScript aren't really arrays at all. They're just objects that:

- Inherit from `Array.prototype`.
- Have special behavior for a property named `length`.
- Have special behavior for properties with names that match the definition of an [*array index*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type) (a string that, when converted to a number `n`, is in the range 0 <= n < 2<sup>32</sup> - 1). These are the properties that correspond to the array entries. We generally write them without quotes (`myArray[0]`), but officially they are strings.
- Have their own literal form (`[]`).

Since they're objects, they can have properties as well:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
a.answer = 42;
console.log(a.answer); // 42
```

JavaScript itself makes use of this fact in a couple of places (but not many), including the `RegExp.prototype.exec` function as you discovered. Another place is in the first argument passed to a [*tag function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), which has entries for the string segments from the template and a `raw` property with the raw version of those segments.

More on my anemic little blog: [*A Myth of Arrays*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)

Comment: so how can I specify properties for an array

Comment: @AyushMangal - I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: Arrays in JS arent like arrays in PHP they arent associative they are indexed

Comment: also note `[] === []` is false

Comment: I meant how can I declare an array in JS whilst adding some properties to it

Comment: ['prop'] ?? I dont really understand your question

Comment: @AyushMangal - The literal notation for arrays only lets you specify array entries, not other properties. So you add them after-the-fact as I did in the last example in the answer (which I may have added while you were writing your first comment above).

Comment: like in the above case say I wanted to declare an array obj1 the same as obj so how should I have written the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah it was while I was writing ... thanks for the help